# Avoid visitors viewing the iframe content in a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser

I have an IFrame with an external content which i can't modify because of [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

My problem is i want to avoid visitors viewing the iframe-content out of the context of the main page (e.g. because they followed a link in search-results) but i have no control of it !

When people click a link or something in the page, it is open in a new tab and not inside the iframe ! All i want is a full embedded browser.

How can i avoid this if i don't have control of the iframe content ? I can see the html with the "inspect element" function of the browser but i cannot do it with javascript because of Same-Origin-Policy.

Comment: perhaps try to give more details? I still don't understand what you're really asking.. are you asking how to change content on an iframed page, despite acknowledging that you can't, because of XSS?

Comment: Rule #1 of the web: If you don't want people seeing it, don't put it online. Right-click, inspect element DONE! You cannot stop it.